# Unable to configure Site to Site VPN between Cisco Router & Cisco ASA and permit SSH

Tags: router, cisco-asa, vpn, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

I am performing configuration on Cisco ASA and Cisco Router from the packet tracer. I am attempting to allow the external network (172.16.22.100 255.255.255.0) to access the internal server which is 192.168.50.50 255.255.255.0 via site to site VPN on router and ASA and access the SSH & FTP service from the internal server. After completing the commands, VPN is not reaching anybody and also, I do not know on how to allow SSH & FTP after configuring VPN. I also need to configure NAT and configure static NAT but unable to comprehend on how to start. Here is the network diagram below. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv2p1.png

I have inputted the commands for Cisco ASA

```
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 198.155.251.100

crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2 
 lifetime 864000

crypto ikev1 enable outside

tunnel-group 198.155.251.100 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 198.155.251.100 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key cisco12345

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set VPN-SET esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto map VPN-MAP 10 set peer 198.155.251.100
crypto map VPN-MAP 10 set ikev1 transform-set VPN-SET

object network LOCAL-NET
 subnet 192.168.50.0 255.255.255.0

object network REMOTE-NET
 subnet 172.16.22.0 255.255.255.0

access-list VPN-ACL extended permit ip object LOCAL-NET object REMOTE-NET 

crypto map VPN-MAP 10 match address VPN-ACL
crypto map VPN-MAP interface outside
```

```
crypto isakmp policy 10
 authentcation pre-share
 encryption aes
 group 2
 hash sha
 lifetime 86400
 exit

crypto isakmp key cisco12345 address 192.133.250.100
crypto ipsec transform-set VPN-SET esp-aes esp-sha-hmac

crypto MAP VPN-MAP 10 ipsec-isakmp
 set peer 192.133.250.100
 set transform-set VPN-SET
 match address VPN-ACL
 
ip access-list extended VPN-ACL
 permit ip 172.16.22.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.50.0 0.0.0.255
 
interface e0/1
 crypto map VPN-MAP
```

I expect the VPN to be reaching from both network and do I need to configure ASA to allow SSH to access Internal network. if yes, why is it needed and how?

Comment: You appear to have posted the same configuration twice. You need to share the full configuration of both devices in order for anyone to help you. 

As for allowing SSH, generally once the VPN tunnel is functional, you do not need to specifically allow SSH, it will be allowed by the VPN tunnel policy and NAT configuration.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer, I have done the edit. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

On the ASA you need to add configuration to implement NAT 'bypass' (really it is doing NAT but without changing the IP addresses) such as:

```
nat (inside,any) source static LOCAL-NET LOCAL-NET destination static REMOTE-NET REMOTE-NET no-proxy-arp route-lookup
```

On the IOS router, you need to similarly deny NAT on traffic that will transit the VPN tunnel:

```
access-list 111 remark NAT exemption access-list
access-list 111 deny   ip 172.16.22.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.50.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 111 permit ip 172.16.22.0 0.0.0.255 any
route-map nonat permit 10
 match ip address 111
ip nat inside source route-map nonat interface e0/1 overload
```

Your NAT config on your IOS router may be substantially more complex, depending on your specific circumstances.

[This page has more guidance](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios/218432-configure-a-site-to-site-ipsec-ikev1-tun.html) and you might note they recommend the use of the command 'mode tunnel' under the definition of the crypto transform-set on the IOS configuration. I am not sure if that is default or not.

That page also has very useful verification and debugging commands you can use.